# Access a GitHub issue comment body using GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I used Khan package to trigger an GitHub action when a PR is being submitted with specific comment, I was managed to do that with his package, **but I cannot retrieve the comment body**.

Can someone guide me on how?

```
'Terraform GitHub Actions'
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened]
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: khan/pull-request-comment-trigger@master
        id: check
        with:
          trigger: 'account-'
          prefix_only: true
          reaction: rocket
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
      - run: echo '${{ github.event.comment.body }}'
        if: steps.check.outputs.triggered == 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: looks like this is broken.

It looks like the `khan/pull-request-comment-trigger` github action returns the comment body as an output. Try accessing it using `steps.check.outputs.comment_body`. A fixed excerpt from your code:

```yaml
      - run: echo '${{ steps.check.outputs.comment_body }}'
        if: steps.check.outputs.triggered == 'true'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer:
there is an issue there https://github.com/Khan/pull-request-comment-trigger/issues/6
there is blank comment when using this output

Comment: @user18395927 Hmmm. Right! Tiny comment - would be nice to add this context to the question so it is clear what you are asking about :)

Have you tried using the github API directly?

Comment: Hi, no I did not think about doing that. do you have a reference? I want to pull the comment from the PR. is there an easier way like env variables? I used what everyone seems to be using except it does not work for me

Comment: Looking at the documentation here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

Leads me to this: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_comment-use-issue_comment

And to https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#issue_comment

Which make it sound like what you tried should work. Sorry, no idea :/